# Updating Model Parameter in Domain Adaptation with Additional Features

Tags: bayesian, domain-adaptation, bayesian-nonparametric

I have developed a model where the parameter is initially calibrated using common features (X1, X2, X3) from both source and target domains. Now, I want to incorporate additional specific features (X4 and X5) from the target domain to update this parameter. I'm seeking advice on whether using Bayesian inference is appropriate for updating the model parameter in the context of domain adaptation with additional features. Any insights or alternative methods would be appreciated. Thanks!